# This app can't be activated when UAC is disabled

Tags: windows-8, uac

I'm using Windows 8 and since I'm a developer, I need full control over my PC. However, Window 8 doesn't have an straightforward way to disable UAC, and even by dragging the relevant slider to the lowest level, user account won't get administration privilege, which is testable easily by opening a command prompt and not seeing *Administrator* at the title.

However, when you disable UAC through regedit, (now known as `EnableLUA` hack) you lose Metro Apps.

I want to both be the full admin of my account (not administrator user, my own user), and at the same time, I want Metro applications. What should I do?

Comment: You set UAC to lowest settings.  You can have full control even with UAC enabled.  You can't disable UAC and have Windows Store applications.

Comment: By setting UAC to lowest setting, what you get is not receiving those dirty messages while going around. But you're not admin still. No app is opened as administrator by default, etc.

Comment: Most applications don't need to be opened as an Administrator.  For those few programs that do, set the short cut, to always run them as an administrator.  Furthermore I can do ANYTHING you can do with UAC enabled I just have to approve the action before hand.

Comment: Try creating a new folder in C:\Program Files when UAC is on (even when set to lowest setting) using a command prompt. Guess what.. Access Denied... Your Solution: Start the command prompt as admin. Creating the folder works now but: Map a network drive using this elevated command prompt.. Guess what.. You can't access it through explorer as the explorer is not running elevated. UAC is nonsense for Power Users and its a joke that I have to have it enabled to use Store Apps.