# Windows Server 2012 UAC issues

Tags: windows-8, uac, windows-server-2012

Hello I'm a developer and my workstation has Windows Server 2012 as its operating system.

Because I'm developing for Azure, a bunch of apps **have to** always run as admin (such as Visual Studio, PowerShell, Azure Emulators, etc...) so I disabled UAC with a script because it was forcing me to keep right clicking -> run as admin (which for me is a **major** pain)...

But now a bunch of apps, such as Windows store and Skype won't run saying "UAC is off so I won't run"

My question is: Is there a workaround that allows me to keep UAC off and still run these apps?

The exact error message is:

> **This app can't open**
>   *`<App Name here>` can't open while User Account Control is turned off.*
>   Turn on User Account Control

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the EXACT error message and perhaps a screenshot of what you are experiencing?

Comment: @ChrisE.Avis edited! check it out

Comment: EnableE UAC again and use taskscheduler to start VS with admin rights. This workaround works since Vista.

Comment: This is by design.  You will be unable to run Window Store applications with UAC disabled.  You also don't need to run Visual Studio as an administrator it DOESN"T need to be elevated.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [This app can't be activated when UAC is disabled](http://superuser.com/questions/554230/this-app-cant-be-activated-when-uac-is-disabled).

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Store, as well as "modern" apps from the Start screen will not run with UAC disabled. There is no supported way around this -

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736601